# BuddyBuild does not show `dyld` error

Tags: ios, build, continuous-integration

My app crashes locally with: `dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/[nameOfFramework].framework`.

I've run on BuddyBuild to check a clean install.

Here is the err on BB:

`» t = 11.89s Assertion Failure: <unknown>:0: [BundleIdentifier] crashed in <external symbol>
772
  ✗ t = 11.90s Assertion Failure: _UITests.swift:31: XCTAssertTrue failed: throwing "Interrupting test" -
773
  ✗ Test testTitle failed (11.906 seconds)`

Why I am not seeing on BB the `dyld` error, like I have locally?

Comment: Try to remove unreferenced framework from application(Finder). Remove and add frameworks. also delete derived data.

Comment: @AvijitNagare, I know why I get the `dyld` err, but why BuddyBuild is not showing it?

Answer (score 0):

if this is not visible in the build logs, this should be available in the simulator ones.

They are all available from the logs section of the build's details:

[image]

More information about logs on [our documentation](https://docs.buddybuild.com/builds/build_logs.html)

Let me know if this helps!